# How to change Toolbar home icon color

Tags: android, icons, toolbar, android-support-library

I am using a android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27152138/335640) how to change the color of the hamburger icon to white, but the up/back arrow remains a dark color when I call

```
setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

How can I make the arrow white as well?

Here is what my toolbar looks like when I call setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled():

[image]

...and here is the relevant portion of my styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#194C5F</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/WhiteDrawerIconStyle</item>
</style>

    <style name="WhiteDrawerIconStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: You can use white arrow png icon and replace with black one.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that and just indicate a color as a style... if that's the only way I know I can do it via 
    actionBarDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.arrow);

Comment: ...also the png /com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png appears white

Comment: @JoshuaWitter Thanks it solved my issue, can you also please help me to detect the click on back button ? here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138629/action-bar-detect-back-button-click-in-fragment#29138683

Comment: @JoshuaWitter even if it is white, it gets tinted. Change the `colorControlNormal` value

Answer (score 271, accepted):

I solved it by editing styles.xml:

```
<style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">INSERT_COLOR_HERE</item>
</style>
```

...then referencing the style in the Toolbar definition in the activity:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Comment: Also you can set `colorControlNormal` instead `android:textColorSecondary`

Comment: but that will change the entire widget's color right? @mbelsky

Comment: @mbelsky Note that it requires API level 21.

Comment: @Error404 : it's added in API level 1 as u see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textColorSecondary)

Comment: Hi All, I have tried your code but I am not getting required result. In my toolbar.axml file I am setup theme is android:theme=@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar and in my styles.axml file I have write your given code but navigation bar back button color in no change.

Comment: Does anyone know how to change the colour of the icon on a single fragment instead of doing so globally?

Comment: @FranciscoRomero `colorControlNormal`  doesn't require API level 21

Answer (score 71):

Here is what you are looking for. But this also changes the color of radioButton etc. So you might want to use a theme for it.

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This achieves what I was looking for:

    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">###COLOR###</item>
    </style>

apply the theme directly to the Toolbar.

Comment: The parent attribute is very important.

Answer (score 37):

I solved it programmatically using this code:

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

**Revision 1:**

Starting from API 23 (Marshmallow) the drawable resource `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` is changed to `abc_ic_ab_back_material`.

Comment: set  this one also.       `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: Would this work in a `Fragment`? If so, where would I put this code into? The `OnCreateView` method, the root of the class, or...?

Comment: @AndroidDevBro 

Yes, just put it in the OnCreate function and remember to update the resource as Nouman Tahir wrote in the revision (using R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material instead of R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha) and getting the SupportActionBar like this: 

((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

Answer (score 14):

This answer maybe too late, but here is how I do it.
Styling the toolbar will do the trick. Create toolbar.xml with following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and in the styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Finally, include the toolbar inside layout

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Comment: but AppTheme isn't referenced anywhere.
is this a typo?

Answer (score 14):

Here's my solution:

```
toolbar.navigationIcon?.mutate()?.let {
  it.setTint(theColor)
  toolbar.navigationIcon = it
}
```

Or, if you want to use a nice function for it:

```
fun Toolbar.setNavigationIconColor(@ColorInt color: Int) = navigationIcon?.mutate()?.let {
    it.setTint(color)
    this.navigationIcon = it
}
```

Usage:

```
toolbar.setNavitationIconColor(someColor)
```

Comment: This is by far best answer and it solves my problem

Comment: NavigationComponent will override it anyway (when it automatically sets menu or back icon for toolbar) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73362085/changing-color-of-back-arrow-icon-of-toolbar-dynamically-when-using-navigation-c

Comment: @user924 Not relevant. This is about whether you use it or not. Some projects don't use NavigationComponent, or they have places that don't have it as it's too late/complex to add it.

Answer (score 13):

Change your Toolbar Theme to ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and set it in activty

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Comment: I was surprised of the other answers, I always use this method

Answer (score 9):

```
   <!-- ToolBar -->
    <style name="ToolBarTheme.ToolBarStyle"    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Too late to post, this worked for me to change the color of the back button

Comment: No..it would affect the normal text too but not the arrow

Answer (score 9):

Instead of style changes, just put these two lines of code to your activity.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.arrowleft);
```

Answer (score 8):

Well there is a more easy way to do this

```
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
arrow = drawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable();
```

And then

```
arrow.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
```

Answer (score 6):

Wasn't able to color it with the solutions here for some reason. But using `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar` instead you can use

```
app:navigationIconTint="@color/black"
```

See: https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#regular-top-app-bar

Comment: NavigationComponent will override it anyway (when it automatically sets menu or back icon for toolbar) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73362085/changing-color-of-back-arrow-icon-of-toolbar-dynamically-when-using-navigation-c

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me:

```
public static Drawable changeBackArrowColor(Context context, int color) {
    String resName;
    int res;

    resName = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ? "abc_ic_ab_back_material" : "abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha";
    res = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

    final Drawable upArrow = context.getResources().getDrawable(res);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    return upArrow;
}

...

getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(changeBackArrowColor(this, Color.rgb(50, 50, 50)));               
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Also, if you want to change the toolbar text color:

```
Spannable spannableString = new SpannableString(t);
spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(50, 50, 50)), 0, t.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
toolbar.setText(spannableString);
```

Working from API 19 through 25.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
Set the toolbar's theme in your layout as follows

```
android:theme = "@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"
```

If you want further information

[The curious case of the Overflow Icon Color](https://medium.com/@mbonnin/the-curious-case-of-the-overflow-icon-color-39d8c3497ccc)
by Martin Bonnin

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using older drawable id  "**abc_ic_ab_back_material**", use the new one **abc_ic_ab_back_material** in every api version. I have tested it in 19, 21, 27 and working fine with below code and configuration.

- minSdkVersion = 17
- targetSdkVersion = 26
- compileSdkVersion = 27

  ```
  public static Drawable changeBackArrowColor(Context context, int color) {
  int res;
  res = context.getResources().getIdentifier("abc_ic_ab_back_material", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
  if (res == 0)
      return null;
  final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, res);
  upArrow.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

  return upArrow;
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

This is best and easier option.
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_24);

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019371/14291243

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32099644)