# Android change color of home arrow in android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to change color of home arrow indicator in custom toolbar.
There is list of examples that I found but nothing worked for me.

**Here is my layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/title_bar_toolbar_id"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:colorControlNormal="@color/hamburger_color"
    android:background="@color/custom_theme_color" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/base_title_bar_toolbar_id_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_calendar_toolbar_change_view_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/select_semester_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/base_title_bar_toolbar_header"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            style="@style/CustomToolBarTitleStyleBase"
            android:text="@string/calendar" />

        <ImageView
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:id="@+id/activity_calendar_toolbar_save_date_to_calendar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/save_date_to_calendar"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_calendar_toolbar_select_semester_to_show"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/select_semester_to_show"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:padding="13dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**The styles are:**

```
<style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/hamburger_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/hamburger_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/hamburger_color</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>

    <!-- Support library com`enter code here`patibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

I tried all possibilities that I found in examples,
but nothing worked for  me.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620883/how-to-change-toolbar-home-icon-color

Answer (score 1):

Haha, this is one of the most frustrating styling issues in Android right now...

Try creating a style like this

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000000</item> 
</style>
```

and using it in your Activity (you will probably want to merge it with your current style, as it is just the parent and this one param that matters) and of course replace the #000000 with some other color.

Comment: Dont understand how  i can have action bar if parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar  i will get exception in  function call getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.activity_calendar_toolbar);

Comment: .NoActionBar affects the ActionBar not the Toolbar you set manually :)

Comment: How can i solve issue if  i need that toolbar will be part of my custom action bar    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.activity_calend‌​ar_toolbar);     actually i will need the same for overflow icon.

Comment: How do you set your toolbar as the actionBar?

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.activity_calend‌​‌​ar_toolbar);

Comment: Good. So using the .NoActionBar theme should not affect showing of the Toolbar. Try it :-)

Comment: This is layout toolbar xml node                 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/title_bar_toolbar_id"
    app:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/custom_theme_color"
    >

Comment: Style is <style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/hamburger_color</item>
    </style>  Not helping :(

Comment: But are you actualy using the style?

Comment: app:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need a separate `ImageView` for your arrow navigation button. Just use the one from support design resources which will resize automatically according to the screen size.

```
Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(upArrow);
```

Comment: ImageView for another purpose. Home Button enabled by the code  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); I dont want change color of Arrow from code cause resource changed from API 23, and in future it can be changed even more. IMHO best aproach is styles file.