# android hamburger button color change using Material component theme

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, android-theme, material-components-android

[image: Screenshot]

My hamburger button is not changing its color,
I have changed color on primary to black color and colorprimary to white, then why hamburger is white?
Everything was fine in Appcompat theme , I changed to material components theme so automatically this menu button became white

my material theme is,

```
 <style name="AppMaterialCOmponentsTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">

    <!--background color-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/secondaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/colorTranslucent</item>
    <item name="itemRippleColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

My layout is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.recipeapp.marathi.activities.HomeActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:title="@string/app_name"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_adunit_id">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/bottomappbar"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item"
                app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomappbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:background="@drawable/round_nav"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_navigation" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I'm new to MDC, pls help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Toolbar home icon color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620883/how-to-change-toolbar-home-icon-color)

Comment: Are you using a Toolbar?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes custom toolbar but menu button is added automatically,It was black, I changed theme to MaterialComponents thats why it became white. pls help

Comment: post your layout pls

Comment: @HenryTwist no sir, the link you provided showing Appcompat theme but I'm using Material components theme.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti pls check I have added layout , edited.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Material Components Theme and androidx `Toolbar` to change the navigation icon you can use:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar"
    ...>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <!-- color used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/myColor</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: thankss al lot, it worked. But I had already sat dark color as colorOnPrimary in app theme   like this  <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/secondaryDarkColor</item>

why was not it working, it was sat on the entire app.

Comment: @noob_android You are right. I'am checking it.