# How to change Toolbar home icon(back arrow) color in new material theme?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, android-appcompat, android-tablayout

I tried everything one by one present on links like

[How to change color of the back arrow in the new material theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788464/how-to-change-color-of-the-back-arrow-in-the-new-material-theme)

[How to change Toolbar home icon color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620883/how-to-change-toolbar-home-icon-color)

[Change toolbar back arrow color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581408/change-toolbar-back-arrow-color)

[How to change change text and arrow color on Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151817/how-to-change-change-text-and-arrow-color-on-toolbar)

[Android: unable to change color of back arrow navigation icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706887/android-unable-to-change-color-of-back-arrow-navigation-icon)

etc,

But nothing works for me.

My layout xml code,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp" />
```

in styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/background_tab_item</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/jd_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/jd_white</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_tab_item</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/jd_white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/jd_white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyApp.ActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/WidgetStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/jd_white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/jd_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/jd_white</item>
</style>

<style name="WidgetStyle" parent="style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/jd_white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- change color the arrow or three lines -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/jd_white</item>
</style>

<!-- Style for the navigation drawer icon -->
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/jd_white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/jd_white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/tab_layout_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

Also tried adding below to onCreate()

```
  Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

Nothing working, still it's color is black, 
What wrong I'm doing?? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple, this worked for me:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make your own asset in whatever colour you like and then place it on the toolbar.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.YOUR_ASSET);
```

Comment: but what in case if drawer open? By default three lines image changes to black arrow when drawer is opened(that also with animation), Can I achieve the same with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this style as your android:theme for Toolbar:

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/jd_white</item>
</style>
```

like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

after countless hack and plain weird situations , this works like charm

```
 <style name="App"/>
<style name="App.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:id">@id/toolbar</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
</style>
<style name="App.Toolbar.Transparent">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```